# Next Scene Not Loading

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is that when all the enemies are killed the scene that should be loaded is not loading. I did add the scene to the Build setting (it has an index of 3) but it is still not loading. The script I created is attached to an empty object and not directly to the sprite (is that okay?). Can someone tell me why the scene isn't loading? Thank you.

This image is for to show you the EnemySpawner empty object inspector
[image]

EnemySpawner Script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] GameObject EnemyPreFab;
[SerializeField] int MaxEnemies = 30;
[SerializeField] float EnemySpawnTime = 1.00001f;
[SerializeField] GameObject FirstWaypoint;
int CurrentNumOfEnemies = 0;
public LevelManager myLevelManager;
public int maximumnumberofhits = 0;
int timesEnemyHit;



IEnumerator SpawningEnemies()
{
    while(CurrentNumOfEnemies <= MaxEnemies)
    {
        GameObject Enemy = Instantiate(EnemyPreFab, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        CurrentNumOfEnemies++;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(EnemySpawnTime);
    }
}

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawningEnemies());
    timesEnemyHit = 0;
    if (this.gameObject.tag == "EnemyHit")
    {
        CurrentNumOfEnemies++;
    }


}

void OnCollisionEnter2D()
{
    timesEnemyHit++;
    if (timesEnemyHit == maximumnumberofhits)
    {
        CurrentNumOfEnemies--;
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    if (CurrentNumOfEnemies == 0)
    {
        myLevelManager.LoadLevel("NextLevelMenu");
        Debug.Log("LevelLoaded");
    }
   }

}
```

LevelManger script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour {
 public void LoadLevel(string name)
 {
    print("Level loading requested for" + name);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(name);
  }
}
```

EnemyShooting Script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyShooting : MonoBehaviour {


[SerializeField] float EnemyLaserSpeed = 10f;
[SerializeField] float EnemyLaserFireTime;
[SerializeField] GameObject LaserBulletEnemyPreFab;
[SerializeField] int MaxNumberOfHits = 1;
int CurrentNumberOfHits = 0;
Coroutine FireCoroutine;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if(collider.gameObject.tag == "PlayerLaser")
    {
        if(CurrentNumberOfHits < MaxNumberOfHits)
        {
            CurrentNumberOfHits++;
            Destroy(collider.gameObject);
            Score.ScoreValue += 2;//The user will be rewarded 1 point
        }
    }
}



void DestroyEnemy()
{
    if(CurrentNumberOfHits >= MaxNumberOfHits)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

private void Fire()
{
    FireCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ShootContinuously());
}

void BecomeVisible()
{
    Fire();
}

IEnumerator ShootContinuously()
{
    while (true)
    {
        GameObject LaserBulletEnemy = Instantiate(LaserBulletEnemyPreFab, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        LaserBulletEnemy.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, EnemyLaserSpeed);
        EnemyLaserFireTime = Random.Range(0.5f, 0.9f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(EnemyLaserFireTime);
    }
}
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    BecomeVisible();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    DestroyEnemy();

   }
}
```

EnemyPathing script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyPathing : MonoBehaviour {
[SerializeField] List<Transform> WayPoints;
[SerializeField] float EnemyMovingSpeed = 5f;
int WayPointIndex = 0; 

void EnemyMoving()
{
    if (WayPointIndex <= WayPoints.Count - 1)
    {
        var TargetedPosition = WayPoints[WayPointIndex].transform.position; //The position of where the enemy needs to go
        TargetedPosition.z = 0f;
        var MoveThisFrame = EnemyMovingSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(this.transform.position, TargetedPosition, MoveThisFrame);

        if(transform.position == TargetedPosition)
        {
            WayPointIndex++;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    transform.position = WayPoints[WayPointIndex].transform.position;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    EnemyMoving();

 }
}
```

Comment: Please append the code of MyLevelManager. :)

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Have you tried putting `Debug.Log()`s in your code to verify that the LoadLevel code is actually triggering?

Comment: The script of levelmanager is added and I did add the debug.log just now but nothing  is printing that it is loaded

Comment: Thank you, please view @Andrea's answer, I think it will set you on a path to solving your issue. Btw, that LevelManager doesn't need to be assigned to a GameObject since it doesn't do anything as a GameObject. You could make it static and call it from anywhere, without binding the GameObject to each script that wants to use it.

Comment: So I need to change public void LoadLevel(string name) to public static void LoadLevel(string name) ?

Comment: Not quite, I can show you. Please add the Enemy code, if you have any.

Comment: I updated my answer with loads of stuff that should solve your issues. :) Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you so very much! You are the best!

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]. This is also not a valid use of the [tag:visual-studio] tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

You're checking for collisions on the SPAWNER; when someone hits the Spawner it counts down enemies. But the Spawner doesn't have a collision box in the screenshot so it can never be hit. The Scene changing code can never be called.

So the game, based on the code, looks like this:

1. Spawn X enemies,
2. Hit the Spawner X times,
3. (Removed: Destroy the Spawner,)
4. Change scene.

I'm guessing this is conceptually incorrect and you actually want to check collisions on the spawned enemies, which will then count up the amount of destroyed enemies, and change the scene when they are all dead.

---

#### Solution

Conceptually, what you want is:

1. Spawn X enemies
2. Count up variable for every enemy
3. On Enemy death, count it down
4. When 0, change scene

#### So how do we code this?

Well, every enemy needs a reference to the object that holds the count. You can do this in several ways, when I personally do it I usually have just one spawner that is responsible for everyone so I make that one a Singleton, that can be references from anywhere:

EnemySpawner

```
public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static Spawner Instance = null;
    int CurrentNumOfEnemies = 0;
    // ... etc

    void Start() 
    {
        if (Instance == null)
             Instance = this;

        // Spawn enemies like you do already, CurrentNumOfEnemies++ for every spawned
    }

    public OnEnemyDeath() {
        CurrentNumOfEnemies--;
        if (CurrentNumOfEnemies < 1) 
        {
            // You killed everyone, change scene: 
            LevelManager.LoadLevel("Your Level");
        }
    }

}
```

Enemy script (I don't know how your current code looks, but here's a minimal solution based on how I **THINK** your code looks):

```
void OnDestroy() 
{
    // This will run automatically when you run Destroy() on this gameObject
    EnemySpawner.Instance.OnEnemyDeath(); // Tell the EnemySpawner that someone died
}
```

This will only work if you have exactly only ONE spawner. If you have multiple ones you will have to send a reference to the instance of its spawner to every spawned enemy. I can show you how to do ths too, if you wish.

---

#### Bonus content

LevelManager doesn't need to be on a GameObject, it can be static instead:

1. Remove the LevelManager script from any GameObject
2. Change your LevelManager code to this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public static class LevelManager 
{
    public static void LoadLevel(string name)
    {
        Debug.Log("Level loading requested for" + name);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(name);
    }
}
```

Now you can use it from ANYWHERE, without needing to initialize a reference to any script or GameObject:

```
LevelManager.LoadLevel("My Level");
```

Comment: Thank you, Fredrik for your time and help, I understand what you are saying but however, coding is not really my strong suit, could you please tell me what I have to change or add in the code ? Thank you

Comment: I added the following code to the EnemySpawner script

 void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.name == "Enemy 1")
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
            CurrentNumOfEnemies++;
        } I dont know if thats what I was suppose to do but I is not working still

Comment: I actually did this exact feature the other day, [here's the source code](https://github.com/dguise/LD44-LifeIsCurrency/blob/master/Assets/Level/LevelManager.cs#L124)

Comment: But I'll see what I can do to help you. Please add your Enemy code (if you have any)

Comment: I added two other scripts that are involved with enemies. Thank you so much for your help I appreciate it !

Comment: Last question I don't really have an Enemy script only those that I have shown you so the "Void onDestroy()" can I put it in the EnemySpawner?

Comment: Ah, I see your EnemyShooter code now. You can add it there instead, in the `DestroyEnemy()` code, just add `EnemySpawner.Instance.OnEnemyDeath();` and ignore my `OnDestroy` code. Let me know if you want me to edit my answer and add how you should edit your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193039/discussion-between-mizzi-and-fredrik-schon).

Comment: Hi Fredrik thanks to your code it is finally working but as you said I have multiple enemies (coming from the same prefab) so whenever I shoot one enemy it takes me directly to the scene. Can you tell me how I can arrange this, please?
I tried changing CurrentNumOfEnemies < 1 to CurrentNumOfEnemies < 5 (since I will be having 5 enemies on this level) but it did not quite work. Also I have left you a comment so we can communicate in chat in order not to have so many comments :)

Comment: Hi Fredrik sorry to bother you but could you help me to solve it, please?

Answer (score 2):

`myLevelManager.LoadLevel("NextLevelMenu");` is never executed, because you destroy the object in the if-test above.

Comment: Not necessarily true; Destory does not destroy the object immediately  ([read more here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html))- but conceptually this may hint a flawed logic.

Comment: Thank you Fredrik; for now, I keep the answer in case it would help the OP.

Comment: It may be the correct answer though, the scene changing logic may not be executed before next frame. It could easily be debugged by setting a time on the Destroy: `Destroy(gameObject, 1);`

Comment: I removed the Destroy(this.gameObject); but still, nothing is happening

Comment: I added Destroy(gameObject, 1); instead of Destroy(this.gameObject); but the scene is still not loading.